# Logic App http trigger with AAD auth - Event grid subscription validation failure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to create an event grid subscription that will call a logic app every time a blob is created.

To protect the logic app http endpoint, I've enabled AAD Auth following this documentation:

- [Enable Azure AD OAuth for your logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#enable-azure-ad-oauth-for-your-logic-app)

I then configured eventgrid to attach an oauth token while calling the logic following this documentation:

- [Publish events to Azure Active Directory protected endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/secure-webhook-delivery)

While creating the subscription, I received this error:

```
Deployment has failed with the following error:
{
  "code": "Url validation",
  "message": "Webhook validation handshake failed for https://prod-07.australiaeast.logic.azure.com/workflows/5aade5e78ff84281baf17c0ab70a35d8/triggers/manual/paths/invoke. Http POST request failed with response code Unknown. For troublehooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation. Activity id:4d430ada-82ee-43a6-8ad4-467f6de611d8, timestamp: 7/17/2021 12:44:13 AM (UTC)."
}
```

Using requestbin, I checked that the oauth token was attached (see associated [requestbin](https://requestbin.com/r/entqi39vgux6e/1vPqbIvBrbQW4vYeY1R0zhMq40Y))

I've also validate that the token was valid by calling the logic (from postman) using the token from requestbin.

I tired the same using a function app and it worked.
So I decided to try exposing the logic app behind API management service and it worked...

So I'm guessing Azure is doing something special with the internal logic app url: https://prod-07.australiaeast.logic.azure.com/workflows/5aade5e78ff84281baf17c0ab70a35d8/triggers/manual/paths/

Does anyone encounter the same issue and was able to work around that in a better way?

Comment: Could you confirm, that the "HttpTrigger Subscription" with an AAD Authentication (no code parameter in the url query string is used) has been validated and is working well?

Comment: it works when behind API manager. i do feel it s intenral dns/ip issue but just a guess

Comment: @RomanKiss, to clarify the validation failed with AAD auth if i'm using the logic app url directly. If exposed behind APIM, the subscription validation works with AAD

Comment: I have tried to use a LogicApp (http trigger + AEG event validation) with the following invokers:  **case 1** - directly by Postman and explicitly bearer token, *OK*; **case 2** - directly by my REST app with AAD to obtain bearer token, *OK*; **case 3** - exposing my LogicApp via APIM and using case 1 and 2 invoker, *OK*; **case 4** - exposing my LogicApp via APIM and using AEG subscription with AAD Authorization, OK; **case 5** - using the logic app url directly in the AEG subscription with AAD Authorization *FAILED*, note that the same cases have been done with HttpTrigger function

Comment: it's very strength error, when an AEG subscription failed but the client app with the same AAD Authorization has been succeeded. Also, the bearer token obtained by AEG subscription and passed to the HttpTrigger subscriber worked with a Postman POST request. It will be nice to have some underlying tracing at the AEG subscription with AAD enabled.

Comment: It looks like, the problem is only for using the logic app url directly (without the sas token) in the AEG subscription with AAD auth. Using the HttpTrigger subscriber (no url code key) with AAD authorization is everything working well.

Comment: @RomanKiss, thanks for your answer, yeah this is what i realized also, only when you're invoking the logic app directly (AEG subscription), it fails. Not sure where i can open report the issue tho.

Comment: Try to report this issue on the MSDN forum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/topics/single/25485.html